# Provide access to Elastic bean stalk web servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

Planning to run PHP web code in aws elastic bean stalk.  Web code does some api calls to my api server.  In api server,   call checking the Request IP for validating the source. Cant have restriction on Api server level as some api calls are public. Want to restrict the access of some API to only Elastic Bean Stalk web servers and not to public.  Believe Elastic Bean Stalk doesn't have static IP address for web server instance how can I check the Request IP.

Comment: are you using a load balancer?

Comment: Is your API server on AWS as well?

Comment: Do not protect your API using IP filtering, this is old school, from the time IP addresses where fixed once for all in data centers.  In cloud area, IP addresses are dynamic and elsatic.  Use API authentication instead, API Gateway or App Sync both allow to deploy protected API, using IAM security or Oauth identity federation

Comment: Thx will be using elastic beanstalk, API server is also on AWS

Comment: Does your API Server only handle calls from your Elastic Beanstalk application?